# How can I pass options to another script in bash only if they have been set?

Tags: bash

I have two bash scripts, `do-foo-for-thing.sh` and `do-foo-for-many-things.sh`.

`do-foo-for-thing.sh` takes a number of arguments, parsed using getopts, most of which are optional and have default values defined in the script.

I would like `do-for-for-many-things.sh` to call `do-for-for-thing.sh` with any of these options that have been provided, but not to use any options that have not been provided (so that they are not required for the -many-things script, and they single-thing scripts owns the default values).

I've tried to look up ways to do this, but had no luck - I'm not super familiar with bash. I can easily pass in all arguments, but that doesn't work if I don't want to provide all the potential options to the -many-things script.

Rough examples below;

do-foo-for-thing.sh

```
A=default-A
B=default-B
C=default-C

if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
  OPTIND=1
  while getopts "a:b:c:p:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
      a) A=$OPTARG ;;
      B) B=$OPTARG ;;
      C) C=$OPTARG ;;
      P) P=$OPTARG ;;
      \?) echo "Unrecognized option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
fi


do-foo-that-uses-values-A-B-and-C-on-P
```

do-foo-for-many-things.sh

```
if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
  OPTIND=1
  while getopts "d:a:b:c:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
      d) D=$OPTARG ;;
      a) A=$OPTARG ;;
      B) B=$OPTARG ;;
      C) C=$OPTARG ;;
      \?) echo "Unrecognized option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
fi

for P in `ls D`
do
  ./do-for-for-thing.sh -p P
done
```

This currently only passes P in. I'd like to pass in A, B, and C as well - but only if they've been provided to this script (so that any that have not been use the default values in do-foo-for-thing).

Comment: Do not do "for P in \`ls D\`". [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

So remember the arguments and pass them along. Use bash array to properly accumulate properly quoted arguments. Use http://shellcheck.net to check your scripts.

```
args=()
OPTIND=1
while getopts "d:a:b:c:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    d|a|B|C) args+=(-"$opt" "$OPTARG"); ;;
    \?) echo "Unrecognized option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

find D -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec ./do-for-for-thing.sh "${args[@]}" -P {} "$@" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

### 1. Pass through

You could simply pass the arguments through using the `$@` bash variable that represents all command line arguments.
`./do-for-for-thing.sh -p P "$@"`

### 2. Build argument string

Instead of:

```
   case "$opt" in
      d) D=$OPTARG ;;
      a) A=$OPTARG ;;
      B) B=$OPTARG ;;
      C) C=$OPTARG ;;
```

Do

```
   argstr=()
   case "$opt" in
      d) D=$OPTARG; argstr+=("-d $D ") ;;
      a) A=$OPTARG; argstr+=("-a $A ") ;;
      B) B=$OPTARG; argstr+=("-b $B ") ;;
      C) C=$OPTARG; argstr+=("-c $C ") ;;
```

And then:
`./do-for-for-thing.sh -p P ${argstr[@]}`

Comment: `./do-for-for-thing.sh -p P $@` will make `$@` undergo word splitting. Do `"$@"`. `./do-for-for-thing.sh -p P "$argstr"` will not work, as `"$argstr"` is a __single__ argument, not multiple. You may depend on word splitting and remove the quoting, but it's __way__ better to use bash arrays.